# Want vertical navigation bar. Float:left on nav and content, but still can't get them next to each other

Tags: html, css

I would like a vertical navigation bar on the left on my main page. I've put both my side navigation and my main content in divs and floated them left, but I still can't get them side by side.

```css
body{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     height: 100%;
    }
    #container{
     min-height: 100%;
     position: relative;
    }
    #header{
     background: #ff0;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 100%; /* This will make the Header 100% of the width of the container */
     height: 162px; /* This will stop the Header form stretching */
     background-image: url("../logo.jpg"); /* This will display the header and ensure its size it the current size of the page. */
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #body{
     padding: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 80px; /* Height of the footer */
    }
    #footer{
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 80px; /* Height of the footer */
     background: #6cf;
    }

    ul{
     font-size: x-large;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    li{
 margin: 0 0 5px 0;
 background: #ccbadc;
    }

    #sid_nav, #main{
     width: 400px;
     height: 400px;
     float:left;
    #border:1px solid red;
       #margin-right:10px;
    }
```

```html
<DIV id="container">
    <DIV id="header"></DIV> <!--- Banner --->

    <DIV id="body">
    <DIV id="side_nav">
     <nav>
      <ul>
       <li id="a"><a href="#">Report an Incident</a></li>
       <li id="b"><a href="#">Resolve an Incident</a></li>
       <li id="d"><a href="#">Search Incidents</a></li>
       <li id="e"><a href="#">Equipment Lookup</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
     </DIV>

     <DIV id="main">
      <p>TESTING</p>
     </DIV>
    </DIV> <!--- ending of body div--->

        <DIV id="footer">
        <br>Internal #: 6037 or 6044</br>
        </DIV> <!--- ending of footer div--->
        </DIV> <!--- ending of container div--->
```

Comment: you should keep your footer inside the body tag.

Comment: your `<body>` is not correctly closed..

Comment: i don't see where i messed up. thx for the edit

Comment: @user1807271 all structural elements have to be inside the body

Comment: After all the adjustments, what crucial piece of information am I missing to get my main next to the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1):

You had an error in your CSS

Replace your `#side_nav, #main` as follows

```
#side_nav, #main{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    float:left;
   border:1px solid red;
   margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: no `#` is needed in `#border:1px solid red; #margin-right:10px;`

Comment: right, I just commented them out incorrectly, but that still doesn't solve my problem

Comment: I can't get the side nav and content next to each other

Comment: it is working..try changing the width from 400px to some 200px and you will be able to see the change.

Comment: i see the change. how do i get the footer to stay at the bottom?

Comment: Try adding `top: 100%;` to `#footer`

Comment: If it didnt work, then do it after removing `position:relative` from `#container`

Answer (score 0):

You are spelling sid_nav is css, and side_nav in html.